# String index out of range with word to phone number convertion

Tags: java, text

So i have created this code to convert words into phone numbers, but when i try to run this code with letters under 7 word it will display string index out of range. But 7 or more is fine. How do i fix this? If so how do i set the string range?

```
{  
System.out.println("Enter a word to be converted: ");
String  telLetter = console.next ();
telLetter = telLetter.toUpperCase();
String  telNumber="7";
int count=0;
int  i=0;
while(count <7)

{switch(telLetter.charAt(i))
 {case 'A':case 'B':case 'C': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
              telNumber += "2";
              count++;
      break;
  case 'D':case 'E':case 'F': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
               telNumber += "3";
              count++;
      break;
   case 'G':case 'H':case 'I': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':
              telNumber += "4";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'J':case 'K':case 'L': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':

              telNumber += "5";
             count++;
      break;
    case 'M':case 'N':case 'O': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':
          telNumber += "6";
              count++;
      break; 
    case 'P':case 'R':case 'S': case 'p': case 'r': case 's':
              telNumber += "7";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'T':case 'U':case 'V': case 't': case 'u': case 'v': 
            telNumber += "8";   
            count++;
      break;
    case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
         telNumber += "9";
         count++;
      break;
      }
    if(  count==3) {
       telNumber += "-";
   }
   i++;
           }     
System.out.println( telNumber );

}


}}
```

Comment: Do you actually need both `i` and `count`?

Answer (score 1):

**Fixes in code:**

1. Use `while(count < telLetter.length())` in place of `while(count <7)`...
2. `telLetter.charAt(i)` can be removed by `(telLetter.charAt(count))`... By doing this you don't need to create an extra variable `int i = 0;`... Its a good practice to keep variable minimum.
3. Use a scanner to get the input... Like.. `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` `String telLetter = sc.next();`...
4. After you used your resources do close them by using `sc.close();`....
5. Also i can see that you are appending `7` at the begining of every number... if that's a requirement then its ok.. other wise you can use... `String  telNumber=""`;
6. I would recommend using `StringBuilder` because in one object you can do it all.. While appending a character every time in `string` you are continuously creating a `new string` and giving it the reference of `telNumber`.
7. Also in your code either remove `telLetter = telLetter.toUpperCase();` or remove the cases with lowercase alphabets.. because on making `toUpperCase()` you are just writing extra lines by writing cases for lowercase characters that are not needed...

Comment: now i got another problem. If i enter any other character like %^$# it will display string out of range again. Why is this?

Comment: add a case having special characters and break the iteration on their occurrence with a message that invalid input...

Comment: What i wanted to know is that if there is a method to only display the case characters and ignore the special characters?

Comment: Use regex for that to check if a string contains special characters... if yes then don't proceed with iteration... and write as invalid input..

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition needs to check for the length of the `telLetter` string.

`while (count <7 && count < telLetter.length())`

Comment: it should be while (count <7 && count < telLetter.length()) not while (count <7 && count < telLetter.length)... kindly check it...

Answer (score 0):

`while(count <7)`
Your code won't end until it has run through 7 characters. Try using `while(count < telLetter.length())`

Comment: it should be     while (count < telLetter.length())     not     while (count < telLetter.length)... kindly check it...

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter a word to be converted: ");
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String  telLetter = scan.next ();
int stringLength=telLetter.length();
telLetter = telLetter.toUpperCase();
String  telNumber="7";
while(count <stringLength)
{
switch(telLetter.charAt(count))
```

Change your code like this.
But as per your code, the 7 is always prefixed in the converted phone number.
    String  telNumber=""; telNumber should be declared with empty string.